# Check Results Count in Postgres Function Before Returning

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres function that I'd like to return the result of a query, but I'd like it to return nothing if that query matches more than 1 record.

So, something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFunc(_a text, _b text)
  RETURNS yy
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  STABLE
  PARALLEL SAFE
  AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
    SELECT *
    FROM yy
    WHERE a = x
      AND b = y;
END;
$$;
```

Except, it should return nothing if that query matches more than 1 record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFunc(_a text, _b text)
  RETURNS SETOF yy -- To be able to return "nothing"
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  STABLE
  PARALLEL SAFE
  AS $$
DECLARE
  result yy;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  INTO STRICT result -- STRICT allows to check that exactly one row returned
  FROM yy
  WHERE a = x
    AND b = y;
  RETURN NEXT result; -- RETURN NEXT - return yet another row for "RETURNS SETOF" function
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found OR too_many_rows THEN -- When no data or more then one rows
    RETURN; -- Nothing to return, just exit
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess this can help you out.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION database.myFunction(
IN text,IN text)

RETURNS TABLE(firstField, secondField, lastField) AS
$BODY$
--sql string is the variable containing the final sql code
declare sql_string text;
declare regs numeric;


begin
--this is what happens in case count<1
sql_string = 'select 0,0,0';

--now we count them
regs = (select count(firstField) from mytable where a=b)::numeric;

--if >=1, then whe get the whole data
if (regs>=1) then

    sql_string = 'select firstField,secondField, lastField from mytable where a=b';

end if;
--and return to you...
return query EXECUTE sql_string;
end;
```